# Certificate Exclusion Paths in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates

I've an Azure App Service where one single page requires a client certificate (ex: *help/tools/checker*).

In the configuration of App Service, there isn't an option like "inclusion paths", so, I'm including all rest of my paths in the "exclusion paths" list, but, my problem here is that the homepage also is requiring the client certificate. Is there some trick to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, any path that *starts with* one of the entries under Certificate Exclusion Paths will be excluded from requiring a client certificate.  Therefore if one of the exclusion paths is "/", then all paths will be excluded (since all paths start with "/").

One workaround would be to:

1. Use Client Certificate Mode "Allow" (instead of "Require").  This configures the App Service to request a client certificate from the client, but still allow the connection if no client certificate is provided.
2. In your application code, check for the client certificate in the [`X-ARR-ClientCert` header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#access-client-certificate) for only the paths you want.  By writing the code yourself to check for client certificates, you have complete flexibility in the paths that require and don't require client certificates.